# Java JEditorPane always enable text

Tags: java, jframe, caret, jeditorpane

How can I define Java JEditorPane to be able to always read text from the user, include after clicking on button, Now when i typing text and i click on some button on the screen, I need to click again on the JEditorPane so I could be able to typing more text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is lost focus. You can make the button not focusable

```
theClickButton.setFocusable(false);
```

Or return focus to the JEditorPane in the end of the button's action

```
editorPane.requestFocus();
```